# Blender 2.8 no shadow lighting

Tags: shadows

I have a blender object for export into BeamNG. Is there a generic lighting scheme or environment that will not create shadows?

To clarify, I am looking for a no shadow environment in Blender 2.8

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Lighting and Shadows are set in the target software, not the exporter. I don't know what you are looking for exactly, but there are few formats that actually export lights, and even if they do, how those lights act is determined by the renderer of the application you display your model in

Comment: Thank you. I added clarification to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global solution if you are using an environment texture in your world material. 
You can turn off shadows per object/lamp though. 
For rendered objects go into the object settings under cycles visibility turn off Shadow.
For lamps go into the material settings and turn off Cast Shadow.
You can do that with multiple objects, select them all and hold ALT while disabling the shadow option. If your objects have mixed settings for this parameter toggle it twice, to unify them.